# How to allow both :correct_user and :admin_user delete a post by before_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

updated followed by the answer, but rails tells me that

undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

I think both correct_user method and admin_user method need to rewrite, the logic Harts using here is pretty weird

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user_or_admin_user, only: :destroy

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end

    def admin_user
      #i dont know how to write it
    end

    def correct_user_or_admin_user
      correct_user || admin_user
    end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in the way you want to do that, because `:corrent_user` and `:admin_user` are only symbal arguments to the `before_action` method.

What you can do is:

```
before_action :load_micropost,  only: :destroy
before_action :admin_or_author, only: :destroy
```

with the following method in your controller:

```
private
def load_micropost
  # renders 404 on production if not found
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
end

def admin_or_author
  redirect_to(root_url) unless administrator? || authorship?
end

def administrator?
  current_user.admin?
end

def authorship?
  @micropost.user == current_user
end
```

Comment: please check the update, i dont know how to write a correct admin_user method, also, i believe the currect_user method needs to adjust. Harts' logic is weird here. Thank u for be patient!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow =.= sorry